# Getting IPE LaTeX text labels working

Tags: ipe

IPE won't save my file as an `.eps` whenever I try to insert any text labels.

Here's what I have inserted as the preamble:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
```

Whenever I try to save, I get the following error:

`Something is wrong with the PDF file generated by Pdflatex. Please consult the stderr output to identify the problem.`

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

I'm working on a mac if that's relevant.

Comment: I'm working on a mac if that's relevant.

Comment: Edit: resolved. For reference for anyone else who runs into this problem, you may have to add \pdfobjcompresslevel0 to your preamble.

Comment: Which Ipe version do you use?

Comment: I use version 7, but I fixed the problem (see above).

Comment: Sure, I understand that you use the well known workaround, but this is not suposed to happen in recent versions of Ipe at all.  I suppose that you use Ipe version 7.0.10 or older.  Upgrading to a recent version should fix it without having to disable pdf compression across objects in the preamble.  If it doesn't, you should submit a bug report.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a pretty basic user, so I think at this point installing the new version would be more hassle than it's worth, but I'll keep this in mind if I need to use pdf compression in the future.

Comment: I have the same problem, and I cannot resolve it. I am new IPE user, so I do not know much about it, but I can draw the figures and export them to eps, but whenever I try to insert a single letter into the drawing, a new small window entitled by "Ipe: error running latex" appears containing a long code (its begin is given below). Now, what should I do? I am a Windows user, and the version of Ipe is 7.1.4. It seems that I have an old PdfTex, or something. Please, explain what should I do in detail since I am not very familiar to this program. (continued)

Comment: This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159-1.10a (MiKTeX 2.2) (preloaded format=latex 2000.11.28) 18 NOV 2013 03:42
**ipetemp.tex
(ipetemp.tex{pdftex.cfg}
LaTeX2e <2001/06/01>
Babel <v3.7h> and hyphenation patterns for english, french, german, ngerman, du
mylang, nohyphenation, loaded. ! Pdftex is too old. Set IPEANCIENTPDFTEX environment variable!.
l.4 ...NCIENTPDFTEX environment variable!} \fi
This error message was generated by an \errmessage
command, so I can't give any explicit help.
Pretend that you're Hercule Poirot: Examine all clues,
and deduce the truth by order and method.

Comment: Hmmmmm.... I do not know what happen but it works now. I changed Latex preamble as suggested below, restart Ipe, nad it seems that everything is OK (although the field Lateh preamble is empty now). Is there some discussion page for Ipe?

Answer (score 2):

In TeXLive 2010, and probably other TeX distribution released at that time, the default PDF compression changed, so that Ipe was no longer able to read the PDF files generated by LaTeX.

Ipe version 7.0.11 fixed that problem.  Upgrading to a newer version of Ipe should help.

If for some reason you do not want to (or cannot) upgrade, you can insert `\pdfobjcompresslevel0` into the Ipe document preamble ("Edit" -> "Document Properties" and change "Latex preamble").  That will make LaTeX use old pdf compression scheme.

See also [this](http://lamut.informatik.uni-wuerzburg.de/mediawiki/ipe7/index.php/Faqs#Why_doesn.27t_Ipe_7.0.10_or_earlier_work_with_TexLive_2010.3F) Ipe FAQ.